# Why did the convict stop his car to pick up Pee Wee?

Tags: plot-explanation, pee-wees-big-adventure

So in Pee Wee's Big Adventure a convict with black hair in his 40s named Mickey Morelli stopped his red convertible to pick up Pee Wee Herman, an old school nerd in his early 30s. What I am wondering is why did the convict pick up this hitchhiker? Why risk letting someone know his location? Did he just need someone to talk to? What purpose did it serve?

Comment: Pee-Wee's a loner, OP, a rebel.

Comment: There are things about this movie we wouldn't understand. Things we couldn't understand. Things... we *shouldn't* understand.

Answer (score 11):

There is no explanation given by [Mickey Morelli](http://pee-wee.wikia.com/wiki/Mickey_Morelli) at the time that he picks up Pee-Wee while he is hitchhiking to Texas:

> **Pee-Wee:**  Thanks a million.
>                 I've been trying all day.
>
> **Mickey:**   The name's Mickey.
>
> **Pee-Wee:**  I'm Pee-wee.
>
> **Mickey:**   How about some music?
>                 Forget the music.
>                 Let's enjoy the scenery.

Perhaps Mickey is wanting to have a passenger with him to assist him in his escape.  Pee-Wee has an idea to pose as Mickey's female companion to elude a road block set up by police who are searching for Mickey:

Comment: I believe this is correct, if there is even an answer.  This wasn't really a deep-thinking plot, it was a vehicle to get Peewee some (pardon the pun) exposure.  If there was any reason at all, it would have been that Mickey knew the cops were looking for one guy, and having a car with 2 people may have helped him slip through checkpoints.

Answer (score 1):

In real life it probably wouldn't have happened but the movie makers wanted something during the journey so it wasn't just a car ride.